# Ruby Gem LoadError on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In my rails project I called 'bundle install' in the terminal to add a gem but received the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       3: from /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
>       2: from /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`eval'
>       1: from /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
>   /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in`load': cannot load such file -- /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-> 1.16.5/exe/bundle (LoadError)

My operating system is macOS High Sierra.  Any suggestions on how to overcome this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you run `gem install bundler`?

Comment: It states that it installs the gem (version 1.16.5).  Calling bundle after that generates the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a `.ruby-version` file in the root of your project with the version of Ruby you want to target e.g. `2.5.1`.

This will give RVM - which it seems like you're using based on the file paths in the stacktrace - a firm version to target for every command as opposed to `rvm use` which is only has a half-life of the duration of the current shell session and less reliable.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Phil, that did it.  Ace!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the path is for another ruby version
uninstall the gem
then go to your project folder and use this command

**rvm use 2.5.1** and then try to **bundle** again

if that doesn't work because you don't have rvm try to install ruby with rvm because it allows you to switch different versions of ruby at any time

Comment: Hi Andrei thanks for getting back to me.  I am using rvm and using 2.5.1

Comment: what is your bundler version?

Comment: It's 1.16.5.  I tried calling bundle version to check this and it threw out the same error.